# scrapyd running as daemon cannot find spider or project

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

The name of spider is `quotes14` and it works well from command line

i.e if I run `scrapy crawl quotes14` from the directory `/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/` it works fine in command line.

I have scrapyd running as daemon.

My scrapy spider files are present here: `/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/tutorial/spiders`

I have many spiders and other files under the above directory and project is `/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/tutorial/`

I have tried

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=tutorial -d spider=spiders/quotes14

curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial -d spider=quotes14

curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/tutorial/ -d spider=quotes14

curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=/var/www/html/sprojects/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial -d spider=spiders/quotes14
```

It either says project not found or spider not found

Please help

Comment: It is on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the schedule endpoint you have to first deploy the spider to the daemon. The [docs](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html) tell you how to do this.

> Deploying your project involves eggifying it and uploading the egg to Scrapyd via the [addversion.json](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#addversion-json) endpoint. You can do this manually, but the easiest way is to use the scrapyd-deploy tool provided by [scrapyd-client](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client) which will do it all for you.